Is there any way to get setPointerCapture to work with artificial pointer events?
I'm working on a browser extension that creates artificial pointer events and sends them into the page using dispatchEvent like so:
function myCreatePointerEvent(pointerId, isPrimary, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, pageX, pageY) {
    var target = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    var pointerData = {pointerId: pointerId,
                       isPrimary: isPrimary,
                       pointerType: "touch",
                       button: 1,
                       bubbles: true,
                       screenX: screenX,
                       screenY: screenY,
                       clientX: clientX,
                       clientY: clientY,
                       pageX: pageX,
                       pageY: pageY};
   target.dispatchEvent(new PointerEvent("pointerdown", pointerData));
}

I'd like them to work in as many of the same circumstances as regular pointer events from a mouse or touch-screen as possible, and currently I'm trying to get setPointerCapture to work.
Unfortunately, both Chrome and Firefox will report an error when it's called with the ID from one of my extension's pointer events: "No active pointer with the given id is found" / "Invalid pointer id".
Other than something kind of extreme like having my extension monkey patch setPointerCapture / releasePointerCapture / hasPointerCapture to manually get them to work, is there any way to get Chrome or Firefox to recognize the ID of my extension's pointer events in these functions?

@Yogi I added an example of how the events are generated in my extension's content scripts. For an example of how to use setPointerCapture, see any number of documentation pages for it, such as: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture
